# How to identify all the users who have access to a field

Tags: apex, soql

I have to prepare a batch class to list down users who has access a field.

As example : Opportunity has a field say (Tax_id__c). 
Now I want to execute SQOL / or any API to identify number of users who can access to Tax_id__c.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**added**

Whether its custom or standard field you can get the `FieldDefinitionId` from ***UserFieldAccess*** object and then create durable ids by concatenating user ids as shown below:

```
String fieldId = [
    SELECT FieldDefinitionId FROM UserFieldAccess
    WHERE FieldDefinition.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Opportunity'
    AND FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName='Tax_id__c'
    AND User.Id=:UserInfo.getUserId()
].FieldDefinitionId; // Using UserInfo.getUserId() only to get FieldDefinitionId which will be constant in given org

List<String> durIds = new List<String>();
// Use for loop of User Ids to create the list
durIds.add(fieldId+'.0050K000008pGrkQAE'); // add UserId 1
durIds.add(fieldId+'.0050K000008BZTYQA4'); // add User Id 2

System.debug([SELECT Id, UserId, User.Name, IsUpdatable, IsCreatable, IsAccessible, EntityDefinitionId, FieldDefinitionId 
              FROM UserFieldAccess 
              WHERE DurableId IN :durIds]);
```

---

You can get it from `UserFieldAccess` object. You should give `DurableId` in the form of **Object.Field.UserId** as shown below.

```
SELECT Id, UserId, User.Name, IsUpdatable, IsCreatable, IsAccessible, EntityDefinitionId, FieldDefinitionId FROM UserFieldAccess WHERE DurableId IN ('Account.Name.0050K000008pGrkQAE', 'Account.Name.0050K000008BZTYQA4')
```

Collect all User Ids and create comma separated list in form of `Opportunity.Tax_id__c.*UserId1*,Opportunity.Tax_id__c.*UserId2*, Opportunity.Tax_id__c.*UserId3*....`

Comment: thanks but this is applicable only for Standard field. For custom field it shows "A fatal error occurred. Contact your administrator and provide the following error id:
[future_get-9-1573716948]"

Answer (score 1):

You can use isAccessible() for checking user has access or not. Below example checks if the user has read access on the Contact.Name field

```
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Name.isAccessible()){
          return '';
}
```

Below example checks if the user has update access on the Contact.Name field

```
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Contact.fields.Status__c.isUpdateable()){
          return null;
}
```

Please refer page https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS

Comment: Above code is for logged in users.